# Expansion of Riemann zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

I want to prove the expansion for the Riemann zeta function:
$\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\gamma+O(s-1)$ as $s \rightarrow 1^{+}, s\in\mathbb{R}$, without using complex analysis.
I have prove that $\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}-\gamma=o(1)$, but i am unable to estimate the remainder $1-s\int_{1}^{+ \infty}\frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^{s+1}}du-\gamma$.
I think i have to use that $\gamma=1-\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2}du$ and so prove that $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^2}du-s\int_{1}^{+ \infty}\frac{\left\{u\right\}}{u^{s+1}}du=O(s-1)$ as $s\rightarrow 1^{+}$ but i don' t know how to procede...

Comment: It is enough to use Euler's summation formula to obtain this; see the answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706008/continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks, but this does not prove that the remainder is O(s-1)

Comment: In the answer there the remainder is estimated. For other proofs, see for example [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book57/files/10williams.pdf), page $16$.